# Empezando con SQLite

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, sqlite

Trabajo con **NodeJS**, durante un tiempo, he estado trabajando con archivos **JSON** para almacenar información de muchos usuarios, pero ahora me afronto a un problema, la corrupción de los datos (el archivo está siendo reescrito de manera casi constante), así que quiero *mudar* todas las funciones a **SQLite** para evitar la corrupción de datos.

Mi archivo **JSON** posee los siguientes campos:

```
{
  "161104821108080640": {
    "points": 0,
    "level": 0,
    "time": 1483466910038,
    "color": "ff239d",
    "money": 0,
    "rep": 0,
    "timerep": 1483466910038,
    "timemoney": 1483466910038,
    "id": "161104821108080640"
  }
}
```

Quiero que el archivo **SQLite** tenga los mismos datos, para ello, debe crearse una entrada nueva cuando la ID de un usuario no sea encontrado. También necesitaré saber cómo podría acceder posteriormente a esos datos.

De momento, esta es la manera con la que trabajo con mi archivo **JSON**:

```
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./points.json', 'utf8'));
let userData = points[msg.author.id];
if (!userData) {
  userData = {
    points: 0,
    level: 0,
    time: msg.createdTimestamp,
    color: "ff239d",
    money: 0,
    rep: 0,
    timerep: msg.createdTimestamp,
    timemoney: msg.createdTimestamp
  };
  points[msg.author.id] = userData;
}
```

En lo cual, su información se actualiza de manera automática con el siguiente código:

```
if (msg.createdTimestamp - userData.time <= 60000) return;
var addin = Math.max(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10), 5);
userData.points = userData.points + addin;
userData.time = msg.createdTimestamp;
```

Lo que hace es, verifica el `timestamp` de la última vez que ha recibido los puntos, si han pasado más de `1 minuto (60000 ms)`, entonces añadirá una cantidad aleatoria de puntos definido por la variable `addin`.

¿Cómo podría hacer lo mismo, pero usando **SQLite** en lugar de **JSON**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El paquete recomendado para trabajar con SQLite es [sqlite3](https://npmjs.com/package/sqlite3), la gran contra es que es basado en callbacks y no en promesas, lo que hace el código más difícil de mantener si haces consultas anidadas. Encima, los miembros [no están interesados en usar promesas](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/427#issuecomment-98854267) en futuras versiones. Sin embargo, hay un paquete creado por el conocido **Koistya**, [sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite) el cual no es más que un wrapper ES6+ para sqlite3. Otro que, personalmene uso mucho, es [sequelize](https://npmjs.com/package/sequelize), pero éste es un ORM y está pensado para aplicaciones medianas/grandes.

> La API es la misma que sqlite3 pero en lugar de callbacks, debes usar promesas

Lo primero que debes hacer es crear una tabla para los usuarios:

[image]

> **Nota:** si usas Node v7.x o Babel, te puedes beneficiar de async/await:
>   `const expectedResult = await methodThatReturnPromise();`

**Conectarse a SQLite**

```
import db fron 'sqlite';


db.open('estadisticas.db')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('SQLite connected');
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log('Cannot connect to SQLite');
    console.log(e);
  });
```

**Consultas en SQLite**

Las consultas son en SQL común y corriente. Por ejemplo:

Crear un usuario:

```
function createUser ({
  uid, username, points, money, level,
  rep, color, time, timerep, timemoney
}) {
  const sql = 'INSERT INTO users (uid, username, points, money' +
              ', level, rep, color, time, timerep, timemoney) ';
  sql += `VALUES (${uid}, ${username}, ${points}, ${money}, ${level},
         ${rep}, ${color}, ${time}, ${timerep}, ${timemoney})`;

  return db.run(sql);
}

createUser({ uid: 'dfudif3', username: 'johndoe', ...)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Usuario creado');
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(`No se pudo crear el usuario: ${e.message}`);
  });
```

La lógica que tienes implementada no la debes cambiar mucho, solo adaptarla a consultas SQL.

Comment: Un aporte brillante, ¿cuál sería el código más correcto para verificar si el usuario existe? Y cuando no existe, ¿qué devuelve? ¿`null`, `undefined`? ¿O quizás un error 400 Bad Request?

Comment: Para verificar si un usuario existe debes buscar por `id`/`uid`. La función que debes usar para seleccionar es `get`. Por ejemplo: `db.get(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${id}`).then(rows => { ... })`. Ésta función te devolverá la cantidad de registros, si la cantidad es 0 es porque no se ha encontrado obviamente.

Comment: Los códigos HTTP deben ser manejados por lógica de negocio. Por ejemplo, según tus reglas, *cuándo* se debe enviar un 400, un 500, un 403, etc.

Comment: hola tengo problemas con el select me ayudas ?

Comment: @srJJ Claro, publica tu pregunta :)

Comment: ok @gugadev ya la pongo

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada tu pregunta es muy amplia, pero intentaré ayudar...
En primero lugar es casi lo mismo que lo que haces en tu *json* que supongo que usas *MongoDb* pero con comandos *sql*.

Primero debes instalar la librería de sqlite3 con npm, te dejo el link de la documentacion oficial.

```html
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3
```

Luego

```js
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

db.serialize(function() {
  db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

  var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
  }
  stmt.finalize();

  db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
  });
});

db.close();
```

Lo utilizas así, inicializas las librerías, usas db run Create para crear la db

Y usas `INSERT` para insertar, `UPDATE` para actualizar los datos y `DELETE` para eliminarlos, aaah y `SELECT` para buscarlos, es lo mismo que tienes, solo que tienes que guardarlos con **sql**.

Por último no olvides cerrar la db con `db.close()` luego de cada uso.

Saludos

Edición:

Va un ejemplo

```js
var db = new sqlite3.Database(ruta);
db.each("SELECT _id AS _id,huellac FROM personal WHERE _id = $useraux", {
$useraux: id
  },
  function(err, row) {
huellac = row.huellac; //esto es si encuentra uno
  },
  function(err, rows) {
if (rows != 0) { //al terminar la busqueda si no encuentra nada
  insertarBd();
};
  });

function insertarBd() {
  var insertar = db.prepare("INSERT INTO personal VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  insertar.run(id, fechaact, nombre, apellido, cedula, fechanac, subempresa, dpto, acceso, habkyb, huellac);
  insertar.finalize();
}
```

En el ejemplo puedes ver que hago una busqueda por `id`, tu puedes hacerla por el campo que quieras, si encuentra un registro está marcado ahí que lo muestro por consola, si no al terminar, `rows` es 0 ya que no encuentra nada y por ende hago un `INSERT` de los datos (yo en el ejemplo inserte datos de un empleado).

Saludos

Comment: Antes que nada, varios desarrolladores que trabajan en lo mismo que yo me han recomendado usar [SQLite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite) en lugar de [SQLite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3), ya que que el primero añade los promises ES6 y las migraciones SQL. ¿Todo ese código que has escrito funcionaría en SQLite3? Y no, no uso `MongoDb` ni nada de eso, uso `fs` y nada más, las operaciones son manipulación de archivos **JSON** a partir de Javascript para NodeJS puro, sin librerías externas.

Comment: ésto es para sqlite3, si necesitas para sqlite es casi lo mismo pero con la libreria de sqlite envez de sqlite3, yo te recomiendo el sqlite3, lo uso con node y funciona de lujo

Comment: la lógica de tu codigo será la misma solo que en vez de escribir el archivo harás un insert a tu db, en vez de leerlo un select y listo

Comment: Y... ¿cómo añado los campos? Es decir, que cuando un usuario no sea encontrado, que inserte en el db la ID del usuario con todos sus datos (points, money, rep, time...)

Comment: Haces un select del usuario, si te devuelve es que existe, si no devuelve pues haces un insert

Comment: ¿Insert de todos los campos? ¿Puedes escribirme un ejemplo? Por favor

Comment: Listo edite la respuesta y le hice un comentario. Saludos

Comment: En la línea `db.each("SELECT _id AS _id,huellac FROM personal WHERE _id = $useraux", {`, ¿dónde inserto la ID del usuario? En mi programa, la ID está definida como `msg.author.id`

Comment: db.each("SELECT _id AS _id,huellac FROM personal WHERE _id = $useraux", {
$useraux: msg.author.id
  },

Comment: lo de huellac es de mi programa, quitalo y pon tu los datos que quieres traer. Si te parece me agregas al skype alexisni@hotmail.com